# is not public in cannot be accessed from outside package インスタンスエラー

Tags: android, java, android-studio, kotlin

クラスインスタンスをnewする場所でエラーになってしまいます。

```
User user = new User();
```

'User()'is not public in　『mypackage』 cannot be accessed from outside package

Userのクラスとnewしようとしているクラスではパッケージが違います。
調べてみると[英語で解説](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386576/classes-cannot-be-accessed-from-outside-package)が載っていそうですがわかりません。すみませんが教えてください。

//追記 20151104 
newしようとしていたものが、objectになっていたので質問を解決とさせていただきます。
ありがとうございます。
public object User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

packageが違う場合、「User」クラスをpublicにする必要があります。